# How can I can scrape two different things at the same time and store it in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

Here I am trying to get the Event Date and The name of the Event. E.g On 05/08/2018 there is FA Community Shield event, so I want to get the Event name "FA Community Shield" and the date at the same time and store it in the database at `id`!`date`!`event_name` I am able to get the date and store it in the database, however, I am unable to store it together.[image: This is the database Sturtuce]

```
$curl = curl_init();

$url = "https://www.brent.gov.uk/events-and-whats-on-calendar/?eventCat=Wembley+Stadium+events";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result_site = curl_exec($curl);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($result_site);
      // New Version // $domd = new DOMDocument();
    // New Version   // $domd->loadHTML( $result );

$dateElements=$domd->getElementsByTagName("article")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("h3");
foreach($dateElements as $ele){
    $data = (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($ele->textContent)));


// echo "<br>".$data;
    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE date = '$data'";
    $result_site = $conn->query($sql_1);
//var_dump($result_site);
if ($result_site->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_site->fetch_assoc()) {
        //var_dump($row);
    }
}  
else {
            $results_1 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO event_table (id, date, event_name) VALUES ('', '$data', '')");
    }
}

$valueElements=$domd->getElementsByTagName("article")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($valueElements as $lel){
    $name = $lel->textContent;


echo "<br>".$name;
    $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE event_name = '$name'";
    $result_site = $conn->query($sql_2);
//var_dump($result_site);
if ($result_site->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_site->fetch_assoc()) {
        //var_dump($row);
    }
}  
else {
            $results_1 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO event_table (id, date, event_name) VALUES ('', '', '$name')");
    }
}
   $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2 `foreach()` cycles into one `for()` function like this:

```
$dateElements = $domd->getElementsByTagName('article')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('h3');
$valueElements = $domd->getElementsByTagName('article')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');
$count = $dateElements->length;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $dataNode = $dateElements->item($i);
    $nameNode = $valueElements->item($i);

    $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataNode->textContent));
    $name = $nameNode->textContent;

    //do what you want with $data and $name

}
```

Comment: I think we can improve this code. I can see an error occurring if some article doesn't have one of the expected elements, so that association by count would fail. What do you think of change that loop to look all those articles and get the elements inside each article? That would be better. Ps.: I'm writing from my phone, that's why I'm not doing any code, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it would be good idea, but exists html markup is not well structured, because required elements are not inside main each parent element. Asker must work with what is available.

Comment: Oh, I just notice now that he's looking the first article only... That's sad. Your code is perfect. Good job, hehe.